# Preserve/store through raster loop in R

Tags: r, loops, date, raster

I have a large raster stack for which I calculate the max for every two layers. The following loop works fine apart from the 
dates. How can I preserve the dates to my new stack? (I assume I need the `getZ` but I have no idea how to implement it.)

Thanks

Example code

```
m_date<-as.data.frame(as.Date(c('2009-05-01','2010-03-25','2007-06-14','2008-12-18','2016-05-20')))

m_r <- raster(matrix(1:60,3,4))
m_stack <- stack(m_r,m_r,m_r,m_r,m_r)
m_stack <- addLayer(m_stack,m_date)

new_stack<-m_stack[[1]]
new_stackk@z$Date<-m_stack@z$Date[[1]]


for (i in 1:5) {
    # calculate max every two layers (works fine)
    new_stack[[k]] <- calc(m_stack[[((i-1)*2 + 1):((i-1)*2 + 2)]], fun = max, na.rm = T)
    # store the date for each one of the max layers (does not work)
    new_stack@z$Date[[i]] <-m_stack@z$Date[[i]]

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code that runs. It makes an assumption that:

1. You want adjacent dates to be compared (layers are sorted by date)

```r
library(raster)

m_date <- data.frame(date = 
  as.Date(c('2009-05-01','2010-03-25','2007-06-14','2008-12-18')))

m_r       <- lapply(m_date$date, function(x) raster(matrix(rnorm(60),3,4)))
m_stack   <- stack(m_r)
m_stack@z <- list(m_date = m_date[,1])

# sort by date
m_stack   <- m_stack[[order(m_stack@z$m_date)]]

new_stack <- m_stack[[-1]]

for (i in 1:(nlayers(new_stack))) {
  new_stack[[i]] <- calc(m_stack[[i:(i+1)]], fun = max)

  new_stack@z$m_date[[i]] <- m_stack@z$m_date[i:(i+1)][
    which.max(c(
      cellStats(m_stack[[i]], stat = max), 
      cellStats(m_stack[[i+1]], stat = max)))]
}

new stack
```

> ```
> dimensions  : 3, 4, 12, 3  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
> resolution  : 0.25, 0.3333333  (x, y)
> extent      : 0, 1, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
> coord. ref. : NA 
> names       :     layer.1,     layer.2,     layer.3 
> min values  : -0.03990727, -0.46295595, -0.39121706 
> max values  :    2.261900,    2.261900,    1.647811 
> m_date      : 2008-12-18, 2008-12-18, 2009-05-01
> ```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I actually do a rolling max but calculating the mean date is not what I am looking for. Each time from the rolling I get the max rasterlayer and what I want is to keep its date too.

Comment: thank you again. I am a bit confused though, I think that the indices that you use are wrong. My rolling method, calculates the max for pairs of 2 (e.g. max of layers 1 and 2, max of layers 3 and 4 , max of layers 5 and 6). In your example, I think that you use a different rolling window (e.g. max of layers 1 and 2, max of layers 2 and 3). Am I wrong?

Comment: What you describe now is not a rolling method.

Comment: the index that I used in my example, gives me the result that I want and it is a rolling method but each leyer can only be used in on max. Is there a reason why you changed the index? I am asking to see if I misunderstood your code.

Comment: I changed it because you asked for a rolling max 1,2; 2,3. I changed the number of layers because its not possible to do a non-rolling calculation with an odd number of layers.

Comment: I see, my mistake it is more like a moving window rather than rolling.